# Access AWS cluster endpoint running Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am currently deploying a cluster in AWS using Kubeadm. The containers are deployed just fine, but I can't seem to access them with by browser. When I used to do this via Docker Swarm I could simply use the IP address of the AWS node to access and login in my application with by browser, but this does not seem to work with my current Kubernetes setting.

Therefore my question is how can I access my running application under these new settings?

Comment: Define/expose them with kubernetes Service, all other approaches are anti pattern

Answer (score 1):

You should read about how to use [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in Kubernetes:

> A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of
>   Pods and a policy by which to access them - sometimes called a
>   micro-service.

Basically Services allows a Deployment (or Pod) to be reached from inside or outside the cluster.

In your case, if you want to expose a single service in AWS, it is as simple as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myApp
  labels:
    app: myApp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80 #port that the service exposes
    targetPort: 8080 #port of a container in "myApp"
  selector:
    app: myApp #your deployment must have the label "app: myApp"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

You can check if the Service was created successfully in the AWS EC2 console under "Elastic Load Balancers" or using `kubectl describe service myApp`

Comment: Thank you Victor. Although your service launches successfully, nothing was created under Load Balancers section, and I am still unable to access my application. Is there something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Both answers were helpful in my pursuit for a solution to my problem, but I ended up getting lost in the details. Here is an example that may help others with a similar situation:

1) Consider the following application yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-web-app
  labels:
    app: my-web-app
spec:
  serviceName: my-web-app
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-web-app
        image: myregistry:443/mydomain/my-web-app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: cp
```

2) I decided to adopt Node Port (thank you @Leandro for pointing it out) to expose my service, hence I added the following to my application yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-web-app
  labels:
    name: my-web-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http1
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30036
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
     name: my-web-app
```

One thing that I was missing is that the label names in both sets must match in order to link `my-web-app:StatefulSet` (1) to `my-web-app:Service` (2). Then, `my-web-app:StatefulSet:containerPort` must be the same as `my-web-app:Service:targetPort` (8080). Finally, `my-web-app:Service:nodePort` is the port that we expose publicly and it must be a value between 30000-32767.

3) The last step is to ensure that the security group in AWS allows inbound traffic for the chosen `my-web-app:Service:nodePort`, in this case 30036, if not add the rule.

After following these steps I was able to access my application via `aws-node-ip:30036/my-web-app`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way kubernetes is constructed is different. First of all your containers are kept hidden from the world, unless you create a service to expose them, a load balancer or nodePort. If you create a service of the type of clusterIP, it will be available only from inside the cluster. For simplicity use port forwading to test your containers, if everything is working then create a service to expose them (Node Port or load balancer). The best and more difficult approach is to create an ingress to handle inbound traffic and routing to the services.

Port Forwading example:

```
kubectl port-forward redis-master-765d459796-258hz 6379:6379
```

Change redis for your pod name and the appropriate port of your container.

Comment: thanks Leandro. Once I execute that command, I will be able to access my app like: <aws-node-ip>:8090/myapp ?

Comment: This command will enable you to access on localhost:8090. You can test your app like that. It does not define paths. Do you want to expose on node ip? 
If so, you need to create a service for it, a NodeIP would solve for you.

Comment: Launch the command and then it will forward all the traffic to your computer.

Comment: are you using this command? 
kubectl port-forward POD_NAME PORT_CONTAINER:PORT_LOCAL. Maybe you are using the wrong port. Another thing waht should your application show on browser? Try to curl the application address on localhost.